# How do I set an onClick lister for an actionbar button?

Tags: android

I have the following but I get a null pointer

```
sendButton = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.menu_send);

        sendButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                    fbSendMessageTask.execute("test");


            }
        });
```

Answer (score 3):

it depends on how you're implmenting your `ActionBar`. if you're inflating the view that contains the `ActionBar` you should use

```
 sendButton = (ImageButton) inflatedView.findViewById(R.id.menu_send);

    sendButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

                fbSendMessageTask.execute("test");


        }
    });
```

Comment: what is inflatedView? supposed to be

Comment: check this [link](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/LayoutInflater.html) about `LayoutInflator` to know more about it..